# Running Artisan command on an external Laravel project using Process facade returns database error for the main project

Tags: php, laravel

I have two Laravel projects, project1 and project2. In project1, I am trying to run an Artisan command from project2 using the following code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $externalProjectPath = '/path/to/laravel/project2';
    $artisan = $externalProjectPath . '/artisan';
    $result = Process::path($externalProjectPath)->run('php ' . $artisan . ' route:list', function (string $type, string $output) {
            dump($output);
        });
});
```

However, when I run this code, I encounter the following error:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'project1' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

Why is the application trying to connect to the project1 database when I have already changed the path to project2, and the Artisan command is being run in project2?

How can I run an Artisan command on an external Laravel project and get the output using the new Process facade without encountering this database error?

Comment: Can you put the true code in so we can see if your artisan path is correct and there isn't something else causing the issue?

Comment: Please make sure you configured database connectivity correctly in both .env files.
because I checked on my side and it's working fine.

Comment: @Brett this is the true code, the only change is for the path. and the artisan should have the correct path. i tried to list the files using ls -la and shows files from project2 directory which the correct behaviure

Comment: @HassanFayyaz project2 does not connect to database so why running artisan on project2 is showing me an error of project1 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two projects in two folders, added your code and the result is as expected:
[image]

then I changed the database name to 'project1' in the .env file (I don't have a database with the name project1) and I have added a new *get* route to '/' url after your code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    \App\Models\User::where('users.id', 1)->withTrashed()->first();
});
```

and the error I have obtained is the same as yours:

[image]

so my response is: in the project where you have created the route that executes `Process::path($externalProjectPath)->run(`

- you have set a wrong database in the .env or maybe you have multiple definitions of DB_DATABASE in your .env, or maybe you have cached a previously .env configuration
- you have set a wrong route or a duplicated route to '/' url in your web.php or maybe you have cached previous routes definitions

To solve your problem, I recommend you to go into your Laravel project where you defined the route that runs `Process::path($externalProjectPath)->run(` and:

- check that the correct database name is defined in your .env and that there are no multiple definitions (you can try to find *project1* in the .env or better in your whole code)
- check that in web.php there is only one route *get('/')*
- in any case **i recommend you** to run `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`
  to clear your routes and configuration cache

Comment: I want to express my gratitude for your detailed and helpful answer. Your response encouraged me to create two fresh projects and test them, which led me to find the issue. In my case, the 'project2' wasn't fresh! sorry as i thought it was, and it had the following code in web.php: which caused the issue
 
$user = User::find(1);
Auth::login($user);  
I didn't notice this code initially, but your answer helped me identify it and fix the issue. I appreciate your guidance and the steps you provided to troubleshoot the problem. Your suggestions to check the web.php helped.Thanks

Comment: @ahmed Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running php in the wrong folder, it might be using the `.env` of `project1`

Try it like how we setup the cron configuration

```
$result = Process::path($externalProjectPath)
        ->run('cd ' . $externalProjectPath . ' && php artisan route:list', function (string $type, string $output) {
            dump($output);
        });
```

Comment: tried that it gives the same error  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'project1' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: @ahmed does both your installation have the same key ? also did you try clearing the config cache with `php artisan config:clear`  ?